# Cant Press Button (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

2 Friends of mine and I want to programm a Bot that creates Instagram Accounts.
We never used Python before so were all new to this topic.
What the bot does right now, is it opens Instagram, accepts cookies, types in a Email Name username and password. then it should press the continuebutton and, for a friend with the same code it works, but not for me. I cant even click on the button myself, it just doesnt react,
and now the question is... why?
We have the same Python version (3.9)
Below is the code:

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

datei = open('Mail.txt','a')

def getMail():
    return str(requests.get("https://1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=genRandomMailbox&count=1").content)[1:].replace(
        '"' , "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", "")

def getIds(email):
    r = str(requests.get("https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=getMessages&login="+email.split("@")[0]+"&domain="+email.split("@")[1]).content)
    alll = r.split("id")
    for i in range(len(alll)):
        al = alll[i].split(",")[0].replace('"'+"", "").replace(":", "")
        alll[i] = al
    alll.pop(0)
    return alll

#driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/")

acceptButton = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("BUTTON").click()

try:
    passwordInput = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))
    )
finally:
    passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    passwordInput.send_keys("no i wont show u guys the password")
    fullnameInput = driver.find_element_by_name("fullName")
    fullnameInput.send_keys("Peter Berger")
    usernameInput = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    usernameInput.send_keys("Poggedwdaw2323drs69420")
    mail = getMail()
    emailInput = driver.find_element_by_name("emailOrPhone")
    emailInput.send_keys(mail)
    datei.write("\n" + mail)
    confirmButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()

quit()```
````

Comment: What is the error you get.

Comment: Thats the thing... i dont get any Error, it just doesnt work...
If i press the Button normal, with my mouse, nothing happens too

Answer (score 0):

```
2 Friends of mine and I want to programm a Bot that creates Instagram Accounts.
```

This goes against Instagram's terms of service. You will not get very far by automating stuff around Instagram. Even if you can automate the creation of an account, you will not be able to automate the usage of that account very easily. This is probably breaking because they can tell you're automating.

Comment: I mean... sounds logic and all... but why does it work for my friend then xD